# issue with expect to autofill login details

Tags: bash, scripts, expect

I am looking for help in filling the login details in terminal on ubuntu.
I have a script test.sh which when run prompts for the following details in the terminal

```
Enter Auth Username:
username
Enter Auth Password:
password
```

I want to automate the process of filling the details(username and password).I checked online and found expect and have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
spawn test.sh
expect {
    Enter Auth Username: { send "username\r"; exp_continue }
}
expect {
    Enter Auth Password: { send "password\r" }
}
```

when i run the above script i get an error as follows

```
./test.sh: 3: ./test.sh: spawn: not found
couldn't read file "{": no such file or directory
./test.sh: 5: ./test.sh: Enter: not found
./test.sh: 5: ./test.sh: exp_continue: not found
./test.sh: 6: ./test.sh: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
```

Thank you very much for your time.
Regards

Comment: You're putting expect code in a `/bin/sh` script. They are 2 different languages. Change your shebang line to `#!/usr/bin/expect`

Comment: Also, try this: `printf "%s\n" "$username" "$password" | test.sh` -- you might not need expect at all.